# Combining duplicates in a nested dictionary

Tags: python

### The Goal

I'm attempting to combine duplicate dictionaries in a nested dict together for a large amount of dict (~ 10,000).

For my specific case, I'm mainly looking to have all the related information (e.g. Batch & Items) of an identifier (e.g. USERID) be in one dictionary, which is in a list containing similar dictionaries. As an example with a smaller size:

#### Input

```
raw = [
    {'USERID': 'USERID1', 'BATCH': 'NUM1304', 'ITEMS': '105'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID15', 'BATCH': 'NUM1323', 'ITEMS': '122'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID1', 'BATCH': 'NUM1365', 'ITEMS': '98'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID12', 'BATCH': 'NUM1365', 'ITEMS': '76'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID1', 'BATCH': 'NUM1376', 'ITEMS': '55'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID3', 'BATCH': 'NUM1396', 'ITEMS': '151'},  
    {'USERID': 'USERID7', 'BATCH': 'NUM1398', 'ITEMS': '69'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID7', 'BATCH': 'NUM1398', 'ITEMS': '126'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID12', 'BATCH': 'NUM1422', 'ITEMS': '76'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID15', 'BATCH': 'NUM1455', 'ITEMS': '77'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID1', 'BATCH': 'NUM1465', 'ITEMS': '97'}
]
```

#### Output

```
raw = [
    {'USERID': 'USERID1', 'BATCH': ['NUM1304', 'NUM1365', 'NUM1376', 'NUM1465'], 'ITEMS': ['105', '98', '55', '97']}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID15', 'BATCH': ['NUM1323', 'NUM1455'], 'ITEMS': ['122', '77']}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID12', 'BATCH': ['NUM1365', 'NUM1422'], 'ITEMS': ['76', '76']}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID3', 'BATCH': ['NUM1396'], 'ITEMS': ['151']}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID7', 'BATCH': ['NUM1398'], 'ITEMS': ['69']}
]
```

### What's Done

I have already completed the following:

```
# Converts the batch & items values to lists to allow for extending #
  def Corrector(raw):
    i = 0
    while i != len(raw):
      raw[i]['BATCH'] = [raw[i]['BATCH']]
      raw[i]['ITEMS'] = [raw[i]['ITEMS']]
      i += 1

# Goes through two dictionaries and combines their values together # 
  def DuplicateCombiner(o_dict1, o_dict2):
    for key, value in o_dict2.items():
      if key in o_dict1 and isinstance(value, list):
        o_dict1[key].extend(value)
      else:
        o_dict1[key] = value

# Removes duplicates from the original nest # 
  def DuplicateRemover(raw):
    i = 0
    raw_copy = []
    users = []
    while i != len(raw):
      if raw[i]['USERID'] not in users:
        users.append(raw[i]['USERID'])
        raw_copy.append(raw[i])
      i += 1
    return raw_copy
```

### My Attempt

I have used the following, which is very ineffective as it loops millions of times with a larger size, but did function for the example I gave earlier. However, I am looking for something that will function with a larger size, preferably without maxing out my RAM :).

```
  def Combiner(self):
    for i in raw:
      for n in raw:
        if i['USER ID'] != n['USER ID']: # If they're not the same USERID
          continue
        if i['BATCH'][0] == n['BATCH'][0]: # If they're the same dict
          continue
        DuplicateCombiner(i, n)
```

Also, I am using python 3.8.12. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason to use a list of dictionaries instead of something far more performant and efficient like dataframes, which would likely suit the use case?

Comment: I honestly haven't worked with pandas yet, but will definitely look into it and dataframes. Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something as simple as this may suit your need:

```
from pprint import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

raw = [
    {'USERID': 'USERID1', 'BATCH': 'NUM1304', 'ITEMS': '105'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID15', 'BATCH': 'NUM1323', 'ITEMS': '122'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID1', 'BATCH': 'NUM1365', 'ITEMS': '98'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID12', 'BATCH': 'NUM1365', 'ITEMS': '76'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID1', 'BATCH': 'NUM1376', 'ITEMS': '55'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID3', 'BATCH': 'NUM1396', 'ITEMS': '151'},  
    {'USERID': 'USERID7', 'BATCH': 'NUM1398', 'ITEMS': '69'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID7', 'BATCH': 'NUM1398', 'ITEMS': '126'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID12', 'BATCH': 'NUM1422', 'ITEMS': '76'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID15', 'BATCH': 'NUM1455', 'ITEMS': '77'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID1', 'BATCH': 'NUM1465', 'ITEMS': '97'}
]

result = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for d in raw:
    result[d['USERID']]['BATCH'].append(d['BATCH'])
    result[d['USERID']]['ITEMS'].append(d['ITEMS'])
result = [dict(v) | {'USERID': k} for k, v in result.items()]

pprint(result)
```

(`pprint` is only there to show the result nicer, `defaultdict` helps with simple construction, you could avoid that by putting the logic in the code itself, but I don't think it's worth the trouble)

Output:

```
[{'BATCH': ['NUM1304', 'NUM1365', 'NUM1376', 'NUM1465'],
  'ITEMS': ['105', '98', '55', '97'],
  'USERID': 'USERID1'},
 {'BATCH': ['NUM1323', 'NUM1455'],
  'ITEMS': ['122', '77'],
  'USERID': 'USERID15'},
 {'BATCH': ['NUM1365', 'NUM1422'], 'ITEMS': ['76', '76'], 'USERID': 'USERID12'},
 {'BATCH': ['NUM1396'], 'ITEMS': ['151'], 'USERID': 'USERID3'},
 {'BATCH': ['NUM1398', 'NUM1398'], 'ITEMS': ['69', '126'], 'USERID': 'USERID7'}]
```

However, a list of dictionaries with list values that have to be processed in order to match up list values seems like a very poor choice for a data structure, unless there's some external reason that forces you to use this structure.

Have a look at `DataFrame` in `pandas` for a more flexible and likely far more performant solution.

Comment: Elegant solution, but ain't merging dict via | operator added in 3.9? Might need to go old fashioned `{**dict(v), **{'USERID': k}}` way! (or `dict(d1, **d2)` according to PEP-584's Motivation)

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier if you create a new list of dictionaries instead of trying to do this in place. Unfortunately, this will be more memory intensive.

The intermediate structure should be a dictionary of dictionaries, so you can look up the dictionary by user ID without having to loop.

This is also a good place to use `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def combine_dicts(raw):
    result_dict = defaultdict(lambda: {'USERID': '', BATCH: [], 'ITEMS': []})
    for d in raw:
        nested = result_dict[d['USERID']]
        nested['USERID'] = d['USERID']
        nested['BATCH'].append(d['BATCH'])
        nested['ITEMS'].append(d['ITEMS'])
    return list(result_dict.values())

raw = combine_dicts(raw)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make use of dictionary's 'get' defaults:

```
processed = dict()
for dx in raw:
    user = dx.get("USER_ID")
    d = processed.get(user, {'USER_ID': user})
    batch = d.get("BATCH", [])
    batch.append(dx.get("BATCH_ID"))
    d["BATCH"] = batch
    items = d.get("ITEMS", [])
    items.append(dx.get("ITEMS"))
    d["ITEMS"] = items
    processed["USER_ID"] = d

[v for _, v in processed.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like everyone's answers are more or less the same.

```
from collections import defaultdict


def combine(data):
    users = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
    for d in data:
        users[d['USERID']]['BATCH'].append(d['BATCH'])
        users[d['USERID']]['ITEMS'].append(d['ITEMS'])

    user_lists = [
        {
        'USERID': user,
        **dicts
        }
        for user, dicts in users.items()
    ]
    return user_lists


raw = [
    {'USERID': 'USERID1', 'BATCH': 'NUM1304', 'ITEMS': '105'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID15', 'BATCH': 'NUM1323', 'ITEMS': '122'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID1', 'BATCH': 'NUM1365', 'ITEMS': '98'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID12', 'BATCH': 'NUM1365', 'ITEMS': '76'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID1', 'BATCH': 'NUM1376', 'ITEMS': '55'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID3', 'BATCH': 'NUM1396', 'ITEMS': '151'},  
    {'USERID': 'USERID7', 'BATCH': 'NUM1398', 'ITEMS': '69'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID7', 'BATCH': 'NUM1398', 'ITEMS': '126'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID12', 'BATCH': 'NUM1422', 'ITEMS': '76'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID15', 'BATCH': 'NUM1455', 'ITEMS': '77'}, 
    {'USERID': 'USERID1', 'BATCH': 'NUM1465', 'ITEMS': '97'}
]


output = combine(raw)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the result in a list, which is designed for sequential iteration, not lookup, use a dictionary. This will offer much faster lookup times and ease of creation both in terms of code and algorithmic complexity:

```
result = {}
for d in raw:
    item = result.get(d['USERID'])
    if item is None:
        item = {'USERID': d['USERID'], 'BATCH': [], 'ITEMS': []}
        result[d['USERID'] = item
    item['ITEMS'].append(d['ITEMS'])
    item['BATCH'].append(d['BATCH'])
```